# Muxing Second video to standalone .mp4 with MediaMuxer

Tags: mediamuxer

I was following this really simple

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaExtractor;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;

// Copyright (c) 2018 ArsalImam
// All Rights Reserved
//
public class AudioExtractor {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    private static final String TAG = "AudioExtractorDecoder";

    /**
     * @param srcPath  the path of source video file.
     * @param dstPath  the path of destination video file.
     * @param startMs  starting time in milliseconds for trimming. Set to
     *                 negative if starting from beginning.
     * @param endMs    end time for trimming in milliseconds. Set to negative if
     *                 no trimming at the end.
     * @param useAudio true if keep the audio track from the source.
     * @param useVideo true if keep the video track from the source.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void genVideoUsingMuxer(String srcPath, String dstPath, int startMs, int endMs, boolean useAudio, boolean useVideo) throws IOException {
        // Set up MediaExtractor to read from the source.
        MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        extractor.setDataSource(srcPath);
        int trackCount = extractor.getTrackCount();
        // Set up MediaMuxer for the destination.
        MediaMuxer muxer;
        muxer = new MediaMuxer(dstPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        // Set up the tracks and retrieve the max buffer size for selected
        // tracks.
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(trackCount);
        int bufferSize = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < trackCount; i++) {
            MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            boolean selectCurrentTrack = false;
            if (mime.startsWith("audio/") && useAudio) {
                selectCurrentTrack = true;
            } else if (mime.startsWith("video/") && useVideo) {
                selectCurrentTrack = true;
            }
            if (selectCurrentTrack) {
                extractor.selectTrack(i);
                int dstIndex = muxer.addTrack(format);
                indexMap.put(i, dstIndex);
                if (format.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE)) {
                    int newSize = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE);
                    bufferSize = newSize > bufferSize ? newSize : bufferSize;
                }
            }
        }
        if (bufferSize < 0) {
            bufferSize = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
        }
        // Set up the orientation and starting time for extractor.
        MediaMetadataRetriever retrieverSrc = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retrieverSrc.setDataSource(srcPath);
        String degreesString = retrieverSrc.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);
        if (degreesString != null) {
            int degrees = Integer.parseInt(degreesString);
            if (degrees >= 0) {
                muxer.setOrientationHint(degrees);
            }
        }
        if (startMs > 0) {
            extractor.seekTo(startMs * 1000, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
        }
        // Copy the samples from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer. We will loop
        // for copying each sample and stop when we get to the end of the source
        // file or exceed the end time of the trimming.
        int offset = 0;
        int trackIndex = -1;
        ByteBuffer dstBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        muxer.start();
        while (true) {
            bufferInfo.offset = offset;
            bufferInfo.size = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset);
            if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Saw input EOS.");
                bufferInfo.size = 0;
                break;
            } else {
                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                if (endMs > 0 && bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs > (endMs * 1000)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "The current sample is over the trim end time.");
                    break;
                } else {
                    bufferInfo.flags = extractor.getSampleFlags();
                    trackIndex = extractor.getSampleTrackIndex();
                    muxer.writeSampleData(indexMap.get(trackIndex), dstBuf, bufferInfo);
                    extractor.advance();
                }
            }
        }
        muxer.stop();
        muxer.release();
        return;
    }
}
```

which is very simple to follow and i successfully demuxed audio from video and video from audio. But now i want to mux another video to an already present MP4 with audio and video. I tried:

```
Audioextractor.genVideoUsingMuxer(video2,originalVideo,-1,-1,false,true);
```

But the problem is that it is wiping the previously present originalVideo and just making mp4 file with vieo and no audio. How to use this to add another video without wiping whatever was present before?

**UPDATE:**
So i was able to solve the problem using 3 different extractors. Two extractors extracts the video track from 2 different videos and another extractor will get the audio track from one of the video. Then using a mux I was able to mux everything to a single mp4 file. 
Now the problem I'm seeing is that the total file size is 112 MB. Whereas the individual file size of mp4 including video and audio is 34 and 40 MB respectively. The final mp4 size only has 2 videos and 1 audio. So the file size should be logically less than 74 MB but whereas now I'm getting 112 MB.
Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: probably too late, but look into bitrate.